# Meteor examples cannot run on OS X: browser just download a file

Tags: meteor

Whenever I run the provided example: leaderboard, todos. After typing the address: localhost:3000, the browser just download a file called "download". Any ideas?

The terminal says everything is OK:

```
    $ meteor
    [[[[[ ~/Dropbox/Projects/JavaScript/meteor/todos ]]]]]
    Running on: http://localhost:3000/
```

Both Chrome and Safari give me the same result: downloading a file.

Comment: What is the file called?  What browser are you using?  Are there any messages in the terminal where you started the meteor server?

Comment: I just cd to the todos folder and type meteor.

Comment: Does this happen for other example projects?

Comment: That is really strange.  I guess we'll have to hope someone from the meteor team sees the question and can give you more debugging help.

Comment: Just to double-check I created the todos example in a ~/Dropbox/Projects folder and it worked fine, though I used port 3001 (meteor --port 3001) since I already had something running on 3000. It worked fine. Try it again in Chrome after opening the View->Developer->Developer Tools and look at the network view so you can see the headers of the response. It sounds like there's something about either the headers or your browser settings that's making Chrome think the mime type is a file of some sort.

Comment: That's really weird.  Is there anything in this file that the browser downloaded?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other processes listening on port 3000?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're running it inside the Dropbox folder. Move it to a different location and it should work.

I'm guessing that the issue is that the mime type is being set by the Dropbox program instead of it being handled by the node.js server on your machine.